# Unable to install libxdp-devel

Tags: linux, networking, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am trying to install libxdp-devel package on CentOS-8 but I keep getting the error message "Error: Unable to find a match: libxdp-devel"

I have also modified the file at /etc/yum.repos/CentOS-Linux-Devel.repo and /etc/yum.repos/CentOS-Linux-PowerTools.repo to allow the baseurl, and I also changed enabled variable from enabled=0 to enabled=1.

Yet I still cannot install libxdp-devel. Can anyone assist please!

Comment: Availability: Fedora 33 .. 36. Looks like the Fedora 33 libxdp was built for "an earlier OS"? I.e. depends on glibc-2.17 .... so no issues with CentOS 8 : `dnf install Downloads/libxdp-*`  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/33/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/l/ → libxdp-1.0.0~beta3-0.2.fc33.x86_64.rpm,  libxdp-devel-1.0.0~beta3-0.2.fc33.x86_64.rpm .... ( Building an el8 version with rpmbuild: No luck.)

Comment: You can also build the new version = 1.2.0 from https://vault.centos.org/8.5.2111/AppStream/Source/SPackages/xdp-tools-1.2.0-1.el8.src.rpm ... to get `libxdp-1.2.0, libxdp-devel-1.2.0` : `$ rpm -Uvh xdp-tools-1.2.0-1.el8.src.rpm` ..... `$ cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS` ... `# dnf builddep xdp-tools.spec` .... `$ rpmbuild -bb xdp-tools.spec`